# The probabilty of non zeros in an array multiplied by it self reversed

Tags: probability, python

i have an array `losses_vector` that is 70% ones. I then multiply it by its reversed self.

for example:

```
  [0 1 0 1 1 1]
X [1 1 1 0 1 0] = [0 1 0 0 1 0]
```

Am i re-calculating the percentage of non zeros correctly?

```
import numpy as np
probs = []
for r in range(100000):
    while True:
        losses_vector = np.random.binomial(1, p=.7, size=n_games)
        pr = (losses_vector.shape[0] - losses_vector[losses_vector==0].shape[0])/float(losses_vector.shape[0])
        if round(pr, 2)==round(.70,2):
            break
    e = losses_vector*losses_vector[::-1]
    non_zero_percentage = (e.shape[0] - e[e==0].shape[0])/float(e.shape[0])
    probs.append(non_zero_percentage)
```

Thank you.

Comment: this is a coding question, and by the way, you didn't even mention which language is the code in

Comment: The programming language is mentioned in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the `non_zero_percentage` correctly.

But I would rather be more inclined to the snippet below; I needed some time to read what you did. Still, everyone has their own style. Cheers!

```
n = 100000
p = 0.7
l = np.random.binomial(1, p=p, size=n)
non_zero_percentage = np.dot(l,l[::-1])/float(len(l))
```

Comment: The while was added to enforce a 0.7 probability because the binomial would jump around. just to clarify. thank you for the responce.